# FFMPEG filters bayer

Tags: video, ffmpeg, converters, video-processing

So I have a script I use to make video clips into GIF's, but I'm having issues with my script, it use to work before and now it's not working.

in my script here I have predefined variables and flags, but it faults on AVFilterGraph by saying `No such filter: 'dither'` but I checked the documentation for FFMPEG and there is a `dither` filter flag, but for some reason it's not working when it worked before.

```
#!/bin/sh 

start_time=00:00                                          # start time of GIF
duration=5                                            # duration of GIF
palette="/tmp/palette.png"                                    # temporary palette
filters="fps=20,scale=440:-1:flags=lanczos,dither=bayer:bayer_scale=1"    # FPS and Scale of GIF

ffmpeg -v warning -ss $start_time -t $duration -i $1 -vf "$filters,palettegen" -y $palette
ffmpeg -v warning -ss $start_time -t $duration  -i $1 -i $palette -lavfi "$filters [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y $2
```

for this

```
filters="fps=20,scale=440:-1:flags=lanczos,dither=bayer:bayer_scale=1"
```

the dither should be a counted as a flag, ie; `flags=lanczos` and use dither method with bayer_scale.

I don't get why this isn't working anymore when it worked before. Nothing changed with my ffmpeg package, I have `ffmpeg version 3.3.3-2~ubuntu16.04.1~ppa1` package installed on my system and this worked fine before. I followed off from this tutorial here http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html

so basically to use my script it's just like so;

```
$ ./makegif.sh input_file.mp4 output_file.gif
```

and then it should produce the converted video into a GIF format, and all I do if I want a specific part in a clip I just change the start time and the duration in my script. Ideally I would like to manual input starting time and duration on the CLI, but I just simplified it down to just input output for files without additional argument flags.

These flags and options provided SHOULD work, but it's being dumb and not doing what it's suppose to.

Answer (score 4):

You're using `dither` as if it was a standalone filter, but it is an option for [paletteuse](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#paletteuse). Change it to:

```
#!/bin/sh 
start_time=00:00                               # start time of GIF
duration=5                                     # duration of GIF
palette="/tmp/palette.png"                     # temporary palette
filters="fps=20,scale=440:-1:flags=lanczos"    # FPS and Scale of GIF

ffmpeg -y -v warning -ss "$start_time" -t "$duration" -i "$1" -vf "$filters,palettegen" "$palette"
ffmpeg -y -v warning -ss "$start_time" -t "$duration" -i "$1" -i $palette -lavfi "$filters [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse=dither=bayer:bayer_scale=1" "$2"
```

Comment: I see... this seems to work.... I don't get how it worked the way it did before until now though where it didn't. :/

Comment: @user94959 It shouldn't have worked previously, but I'm also not sure how it would have.